# Performance issue with QGraphicsScene::createItemGroup

Tags: performance, qt, graphics, qt4

I'm using the Qt graphics API to display layers in some GIS software.

Each layer is a group, containing graphic primitives. I have a
performance issue when loading fairly large data sets, for example
this is what happens when making a group composed of ~96k circular
paths (points from a shapefile):

[callgrind image http://f.imagehost.org/0750/profile-createItemGroup.png](http://f.imagehost.org/0750/profile-createItemGroup.png)

The complete callgrind dump is [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?izmgqnxvwdj).

The `QGraphicsScene::createItemGroup()` call takes about 150 seconds to
complete on my 2.4GHz core2, and it seems all this time is used in
`QGraphicsItemPrivate::updateEffectiveOpacity()`, which itself consumes
37% of its time calling `QGraphicsItem::flags()` 4 *billion* times (the
data comes from a test script with no GUI, just a scene, not even tied
to a view).

All the rest is pretty much instantaneous (creating the items,
reading the file, etc...). I tried to disable the scene's index before
creating the group and obtained similar results.

What could I do to improve performances in this case ? If I can't is there a way to create groups faster ?

Comment: Can you add a little bit more information? What kinds of items do you use? Who calls the flags method and the updateEffectOpacity methods, the group or the items itself? What flags are set on the items?

Comment: The items are `QGraphicsEllipseItem` with the `QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations` flag set. The `flags()` and `updateEffectiveOpacity()` methods are called from `QGraphicsScene::createItemGroup()`.

Comment: And removing the `ItemIgnoresTransformations` flag does not change anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After studying the source code a little bit, I found out that the `updateEffectiveOpacity` has O(n²) with regard to the children of the item's parent item (search for the method [`qt_allChildrenCombineOpacity`](http://qt4-x11.sourcearchive.com/documentation/4.5.1-2/qgraphicsitem_8cpp-source.html)). This is probably also the reason that method disappeared in Qt 4.6 and apparently been replaced by something else. Anyway, you should try out setting the `ItemDoesntPropagateOpacityToChildren` flag **on the group item** (i.e. you'll have to create it yourself), at least while adding all the items.

Comment: Yes ! my loading time went down to a few seconds, which is still slow but sure more acceptable than over 2 minutes :) (I still reactivate the flag once the group is created). Thank you very much !